# Routing Information Protocol (RIP)

Tags: routes, protocols, router, subnet

Hello I am learning networking in a class and currently trying to understand routing information protocol and there is only one example from my networking book as follows (and the same one I can find online):

[image]

How will table C change given that it receives from A the above advertisement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RIP algorithm will only update a local row if the `recived table's hop count < local hop count -1`.

NB. the -1 is due to the fact the remote hope count does not include the hope to get to the local rounter.

- Destination SubNet u: 
  local row hop count = 1. 
  recived row hop count = 2. 
  As recived information does not decrease the hop count, this row remains unchanged.
- SubNet V:
  Local hop count = 3. 
  recived hop count = 2. 
  New hop count is lower however not an improvemtn when you consider the hop from rounter C to A. Therefore unchanged
- SubNet W:
  Local hop count = 4
  recived hop count = 1
  the path via router A will therefor give a path with fewer hops so this row will be updated.
  Next router = A (As we are diverting via the node we recived the table from)
  new hop count = 2 (the recived 1 + the hop from A to C)
- SubNet x:
  local hop count = 2
  recieved hop count = 3
  The new cost is larger than out local copy therefore isnt changed.

Only the row reffering to subnet W is updated.

Subnet Desitnation = w, Next Rounter = A, Hop count = 2.